# Set an environment variable on Linux when running Spring Boot using the launch script

Tags: spring-boot

How can I set an environment variable on Linux when I run my Spring Boot application using `sudo service myapp run`. Currently, it does not load environment variables that are set by `export MY_VAR=MY_VAL`.
Using `java -jar myapp.jar`, the environment variable does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the following command: 
`sudo MY_VAR=MY_VAL /etc/init.d/myapp run`

Answer (score 0):

The sudo command starts your Spring Boot application with root priviliges. Your current user and root user has different environment variables sets. When you start your application with root privileges you need to add env variables as root.

- Become root user:  `sudo -s` and type your password.
- Enter your export command without sudo: `export MY_VAR=MY_VAL`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `sudo -s` because I'm using the sshexec goal of the maven-wagon plugin, and therefore I cannot give any input (my password). But I've already fixed my problem :)

Comment: Yes, in that case my solution won't work. You can eventually add permanent export to your shell configuration file (e.g. `/root/.bashrc` )